# How to install latest version of python-pip in linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I want to install python version 3.11.3 in linux.

```
apt-get install -y python3.11 python3.11-pip
```

python3.11 is getting installed, but giving error while installing `python3.11-pip`

```
Error: Unable to locate package python3.11-pip
```

Comment: What distro are you using?